# Blazor Global Singleton Object - use Dependency Injection?

Tags: singleton, blazor

I have a single CUSTOMER object that needs to accessed / available to all parts of Blazor application , from the MainLayout to NavMenu to the razor components. How do I implement a Global Singleton Object?

I have attempted to use DI in *Startup.cs* like this

```
services.AddSingleton<ICustomer, Customer>();
```

And then in *MainLayout*

```
@inject Customer cust
```

then set some properties.

And then in *CustomerPage*

```
  @inject Customer cust
```

But values are BLANK in CUSTOMERPAGE

What am I missing?  I need to persist this object throughout the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should inject by the interface:

```
@inject ICustomer cust
```

Or register the class by itself:

```
services.AddSingleton<Customer, Customer>();

@inject Customer cust
```

Comment: Or Register the class by itself.